# Correct way to re-use a Socket?

Tags: java, sockets, reusability

My app contains a continuous loop. In each iteration through the loop, 5 to 200 transactions are performed via a Socket to the server.

Previously, I was creating a new Socket for each transaction. However, I think it would be much better to reuse the Socket as much as possible. As I couldn't find any code examples on the web of the correct way to re-use a socket, I am hoping I have done it the correct way.

If anyone has any suggestions to improve this code, it would be much appreciated.

```
Socket socket = null;
boolean reuseSocket = true;

//This method is called between 5 and 150 times, every 10 seconds.
public String getViaSocket(String commandString) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    OutputStream socketOutputStream = null;
    InputStream socketInputStream = null;
    try {

        if (!reuseSocket || socket == null || socket.isClosed()) {
            socket = new Socket(HTCS_IP_ADDRESS, HTCS_PORT_NUM);
        }

        if (reuseSocket) {
            socket.setKeepAlive(true);
        }
        else {
            socket.setKeepAlive(false);
        }
        socket.setSoTimeout(20  * 1000);
        socket.setSoLinger(false, 0);

        socketOutputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        socketOutputStream.write(commandString.getBytes());
        socketOutputStream.flush();

        socketInputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        int b;
        do {
            b = socketInputStream.read();
            sb.append((char)b);
        }
        while(!isEndOfResponse(b, sb));

        return sb.toString();
    }
    finally {

        try {
            if (socketOutputStream != null) {
                socketOutputStream.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}

        try {
            if (socketInputStream != null) {
                socketInputStream.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}

        try {
            if (!reuseSocket && socket != null && !socket.isClosed()) {
                socket.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Jim Garrison, EJP, Jarrod Roberson and Łukasz Lech, if this is a duplicate of another question, can you let me know which question you think it is duplicating?

Comment: What is happening in isEndOfResponse?

Comment: haylem, thanks but I don't think the 'reusing socket streams' question is a duplicate.

Comment: @user1617737: you're right, it's for a different problem.

Comment: Eli Algranti, the isEndOfResponse method returns true if the returned content ends with the end-of-message String.

Comment: Then you seem to be doing ok. Your reading of the socket byte by byte could be improved. If your code is not working it may be the other side is closing the connection